# how I can add parse notification to my application?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an application that I want to use parse notification in it.
I also have a correct sample parse push notification. how and where I can use push it it?
My parse application have these code:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this, " ", " ");


        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
```

and also:

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // To track statistics around application
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, ParseStarterProjectActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

}
```

it works correctly but I don't know where I can add in this code to my main application.

Answer (score 0):

Right now , since you are not using channels or advanced targetting , you can put the code in the onCreate method and push notifications will work, In this way you can send pushes from the parse website.

If you want to send pushes to a subset of devices you can use channels(You can let users subscribe/unsubscribe and send pushes) or advanced targeting. In these ways whenever a event occurs you can send a push to the devices you want from the parse website or from the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to write a custom receiver which can read your push notification and hence act accordingly.

You can follow the following steps to enable Parse notification parsing in your application. I am assuming that you have already included the concerned jar file (Parse-1.7.1.jar in my case) in your project.

**Step-1:** In the onCreate() function in your Application class, declare 
Parse.initialize(this, Constants.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_APPLICATION_ID, Constants.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CLIENT_ID);

Replace PUSH_NOTIFICATION_APPLICATION_ID and PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CLIENT_ID with your credentials.

**Step-2:** Include the following lines in your Manifest file.

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver
    android:name="path to class.CustomReceiver"
    android:exported="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/notification_icon"
    android:logo="@drawable/notification_icon" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        <category android:name="your package name" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Step-3:** Create CustomReceiver class like:

```
public class CustomReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

private final String TAG = "ParseNotification";
private String msg = "";
private String[] split = new String[2];

public static SharedPreferences settingsUserProfile;
private String promoOfferUrl = null;

public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

        Log.d(TAG, "got action: " + action + " on channel: " + channel + " with:");
        Iterator itr = json.keys();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
            if(key.equals("move")) {
                msg = json.getString(key);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSON Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if(msg.equals("1")) {
    // move to Activity X
    } else {
    // move to Activity Y
    }
}
```

**STEP-4:** Write your Push notification like:

```
{
"alert": "Hello World",
"title": "bye bye",
"move": "1"
}
```

You have to go to Parse UI and in the "Write your message" section, choose JSON as message type and paste the above sample. In my case, I was moving to different activities based on the value of "move" parameter. You can design your JSON accordingly and hence modify the code to suit your needs.

Hope that it will resolve your issue.